# win7 pyspark sql utils IllegalArgumentException

Tags: windows, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to run pyspark on pycharm. I have connected everything and set the environment variables. I can read sc.textFile but when I try to read csv file from pyspark.sql, something went wrong.

Here is the code:

```
import os
import sys
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

# Path for spark source folder
os.environ['SPARK_HOME']="E:/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7"
# Append pyspark  to Python Path
sys.path.append("E:/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python")
sys.path.append("E:/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.1.zip")


conf = SparkConf().setAppName('Simple App')
sc = SparkContext("local", "Simple App")
spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=SparkConf()).getOrCreate()


accounts_rdd =  spark.read.csv('test.csv')
print accounts_rdd.show()
```

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/bjlinmanna/PycharmProjects/untitled1/spark.py", line 25, in <module>
    accounts_rdd =  spark.read.csv('pmec_close_position_order.csv')
  File "E:\spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7\spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\readwriter.py", line 363, in csv
    return self._df(self._jreader.csv(self._spark._sc._jvm.PythonUtils.toSeq(path)))
  File "E:\spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7\spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.1-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 933, in __call__
  File "E:\spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7\spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line 79, in deco
    raise IllegalArgumentException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: u'java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: file:C:/the/path/to/myfile/spark-warehouse'
```

Thanks to @Hyunsoo Park, I solved my problem as follows:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder\
    .master('local[*]')\
    .appName('My App')\
    .config('spark.sql.warehouse.dir', 'file:///C:/the/path/to/myfile')\
    .getOrCreate()


accounts_rdd =  spark.read\
    .format('csv')\
    .option('header', 'true')\
    .load('file.csv')
```

While setting your config, be careful about the '//' in the file path. I don't know why when I set 'file:C:/the/path/to/myfile', it doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably this link is helpful.

http://quabr.com/38669206/spark-2-0-relative-path-in-absolute-uri-spark-warehouse

In short, there are config option `spark.sql.warehouse.dir` to set warehouse folder. If you set warehouse folder manually, the error message will disappear.

I have encountered the same problem today. I have no problem in ubuntu 16.04 but, when I run the same code in windows 10, spark show error message like you. Probably, spark can't found or make warehouse folder properly in windows.

Comment: Thanks! This helps me a lot! My correct code shown as above